# How to capture the word between is after certain text after end with some text in regex?

Tags: regex

I would like to find something like this:

```
-(IBOutlet)UIView *aView;
```

I would like to find `aView`, something that I can confirm is `-(IBOutlet)` must be a prefix, but it comes with not ensure a space or another string, after that, we need to string that must begin with '*', until it match the `;`.

So, my regex look like that:

```
(IBOutlet)*\*?;
```

For sure, it can't capture what I want. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to build it up incrementally.  The best reference that I have found (by far) is http://www.regular-expressions.info.  After learning the basics, you can then use one of many online pattern matching tools, here is one:

https://regex101.com

With that, your goal is easily determined (with some allowances for free space):

`^\s*-\s*\(IBOutlet\)(\w*)\s*(\*\w*)`

Answer (score 0):

First problem: you don't have a capturing group so how do you get `aView` back after the match?

Second, the `\*?` means "match the * character literally, 0 or 1 times", which I guess isn't what you want either.

Try this pattern:

```
(IBOutlet)*\*(.+);
```

[RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/gN1kI3/1) can explain what each component means.